# Spring RedirectAttributes: addAttribute() vs addFlashAttribute()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My understanding so far is on our controller request mapping method we can specify *RedirectAttributes* parameter and populate it with attributes for when the request gets redirected.

*Example*:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=GET)
public String hello(RedirectAttributes redirAttr)
{
   // should I use redirAttr.addAttribute() or redirAttr.addFlashAttribute() here ?

   // ...

   return "redirect:/somewhere";
}
```

The redirect attributes will then be available on the target page where it redirects to.

However *RedirectAttributes* class has two methods:

- [`addAttribute()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addAttribute-java.lang.Object-)
- [`addFlashAttribute()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addFlashAttribute-java.lang.Object-)

Have been reading Spring documentation for a while but I'm a bit lost. What is the fundamental *difference* between those two, and how should I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Here is the **difference**:

- `addFlashAttribute()` actually stores the attributes in a *flashmap*
  (which is internally maintained in the users `session` and removed
  once the next redirected request gets fulfilled)
- `addAttribute()` essentially constructs *request parameters* out of
  your attributes and redirects to the desired page with the request
  parameters.

So the **advantage** of `addFlashAttribute()` will be that you can store pretty much any object in your *flash attribute* (as it is not serialized into request params at all, but maintained as an object), whereas with `addAttribute()` since the object that you add gets transformed to a normal request param, you are pretty limited to the object types like `String` or primitives.

Comment: Hi. I have one question is RedirectAttributes  affects the SessionAttribute?

Comment: Is it possible to deny the override of redirect attributes through query params? Is this feature implemented as default?

Comment: why addAttribute method has signature (String, Object) ?

Comment: great explanation, if you use 'addAttribute', you could find the parameter in browser address location.

Answer (score 25):

Assume you have 2 controllers.If you redirect from one controller to
    another controller the values in model object won't be available in the
    other controller. So if you want to share the model object values
    then you have to say in first controller

```
addFlashAttribute("modelkey", "modelvalue");
```

Then second controller's model contains now the above key value pair..

Second question ? What is difference between `addAttribute` and `addFlashAttribute` in `RedirectAttributes` class

`addAttribute` will pass the values as requestparameters instead of model,so when you add some using `addAttribute` you can access those values from `request.getParameter`

Here is the code.I have used to find out what is going on :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rm1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String rm1(Model model,RedirectAttributes rm) {
    System.out.println("Entered rm1 method ");

    rm.addFlashAttribute("modelkey", "modelvalue");
    rm.addAttribute("nonflash", "nonflashvalue");
    model.addAttribute("modelkey", "modelvalue");

    return "redirect:/rm2.htm";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/rm2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String rm2(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Entered rm2 method ");

    Map md = model.asMap();
    for (Object modelKey : md.keySet()) {
        Object modelValue = md.get(modelKey);
        System.out.println(modelKey + " -- " + modelValue);
    }

    System.out.println("=== Request data ===");

    java.util.Enumeration<String> reqEnum = request.getParameterNames();
    while (reqEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s = reqEnum.nextElement();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("==" + request.getParameter(s));
    }

    return "controller2output";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[Javadoc description:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html)
"A FlashMap provides a way for one request to store attributes intended for use in another. This is most commonly needed when redirecting from one URL to another -- e.g. the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. A FlashMap is saved before the redirect (typically in the session) and is made available after the redirect and removed immediately."