# Spring RedirectAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can we use spring `RedirectAttributes` to add a attribute with same name and multiple values, like if I have HTTP request parameter say `place=london&place=paris`, and I want to redirect these "place" params in a `redirectAttribute`.

```
redirectAttribute.addAttribute("place",places??)
```

I don't want to use flash attributes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Flash attributes are redirect attributes. Just add an array or list with two elements.

Comment: Some how I am loosing flash attributes in my redirects, some upper layer third party server code, is flushing them. so can't use flash attributes

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: redirect attributes and flash attributes are very different in the way they work. redirect-attributes are parameter of the redirect url. flash-attribtes are stored in the users session (flash-map). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470824/280244

Comment: @Ralph I've been using the terms flash attributes and redirect attributes interchangeably. I've never actually used the attributes that are passed as a query string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really frustrated that there doesn't appear to be a cleaner solution, but I faced the same problem and ended up doing:

```
((HashMap<String, Object>) redirectAttrs).putIfAbsent("place", 
                                                      Arrays.asList("london", "paris"));
```

This works because it bypasses the way that RedirectAttributes normally converts everything to a String when you add it, since they forgot to override the `putIfAbsent` method...

It works (for now), but I certainly don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mergeAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#mergeAttributes-java.util.Map-) method:

```
String[] attrArray = {"london", "paris"};
Map<String, String[]> attrMap = new HashMap<>();
attrMap.put("place", attrArray);
redirectAttrs.mergeAttributes(attrMap);
```

This will create a URL with request parameters like this: `place=london%2Cparis` (where `%2C` is the ASCII keycode in hexadecimal for a comma), which is equivalent to `place=london&place=paris`.