# how to show validation error in jsp in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to show validation error in my jsp page.

My object is:

```
public class MyObjectDTO{ @valid private TextDTO text1; @valid private TextDTO text2 }

public class TextDTO{ @NotBlank private String code;@NotBlank private String label;}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String creationProjet(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObjectDTO obj, BindingResult result,
                             Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("hasErrors", true);
        return "create";
    } else {
        ....
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}
```

my jsp

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.obj'].hasFieldErrors('text1') ? 'has-error' : ''}">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">my label</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <form:select class="form-control" name="type" path="text1.code" id="selectType">
    <option value="">---------</option>
            <c:forEach items="${types }" var="type">
                <form:option value="${type.id }">
                    <c:out value=" ${type.code}"></c:out>
                </form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
        <form:errors path="text1.code" class="has-error  error"></form:errors>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller redirects to the page create but the errors are not showing. In debug mode there is one error that indicates `text1.code` cannot be a blank.

Answer (score 5):

In your Jsp page add following line

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.obj'].hasFieldErrors('text1') ? 'hasErrors' : ''}">
```

or use `hasFieldErrors()` instead

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.obj'].hasFieldErrors()}">
```

And About `addAttributes("hasErrors",true)`, use `addFlashAttribute()` which is store in flashmap and Object (In your case Error Message will be alive when you navigate to create page or redirect between two controller.) [Look at this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470111/spring-redirectattributes-addattribute-vs-addflashattribute)

In your controller Add `RedirectAttributes` Object like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String creationProjet(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObjectDTO obj,     
BindingResult result,
RedirectAttributes redirectAtt,
Model model) {
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    redirectAtt.addFlashAttribute("hasErrors","ur message");//instead of true you can write your own message 
    return "create";
} else {
    ....
    }
    return "redirect:/list";
}

}
```

If you write your own message instead of true

```
<c:if test="${not empty hasErrors">
     <p>${hasErrors}</p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: i've used this in my jsp `<div class="col-md-6 form-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.obj'].hasFieldErrors('text1') ? 'hasErrors' : ''}">` and in my page i'm not using something to read attributs putted in model, i use this  `<form:errors path="text1.code" class="has-error  error"></form:errors> `

Answer (score 0):

only you missing is put part to model map.You are putting only flag. But you need to put result.

```
if(result.hasErrors()){             
    mm.addAttribute("errors", result);
    return "create";
}
```

Comment: in my jsp i don't use this flag `mm.addAttribute("errors", result);`

Comment: it is not flag.it contain the all binding result collection.just try it and let me know.

Comment: i agree with you but when we put something in the model with this `mm.addAttribute("errors", result);` we should read it in the page but me i use ` <form:errors path="text1.code" class="has-error error"></form:errors>` and its work for non complex object

Comment: my form begin with : `<form:form id="myForm" method="post" action="${create}"
      class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="obj">`

Comment: instead of <form:select class="form-control" name="type" path="text1.code" id="selectType"> try <form:select class="form-control"  path="text1.code" >

Comment: there are no relation between id, name and what we talk about,
for your informations in debug mode there are all the errors in result object and spring  form:error should show the errors in the page, but in this case  form:error dont do that, i dont know what's the prob

Comment: how spring tally with [form:errors path="text1.code"]  [form:select id="selectType"]

Comment: try with @ModelAttribute("obj")

Comment: the object obj is  located implicitly by spring, because i use the same name in the form tag