# Redirect after post modelAndView not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I don´t know how redirect after post in my modelAndView

```
@PostMapping("/admin/nuevo_equipo")
public ModelAndView createEntrenador(@Valid Equipo equipo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    equipoService.save(equipo);
    model.addObject("msg", "entrenador creado con exito");
    model.setViewName("/administrador/nuevo_equipo");
    return model;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: So what is the problem with the code you have posted? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several possibilities... in your case following would be a good fit

```
@PostMapping("/admin/nuevo_equipo")
public ModelAndView createEntrenador(@Valid Equipo equipo, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
    equipoService.save(equipo);
    model.addAttribute("msg", "entrenador creado con exito");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/REDIRECT_URL", model);
}
```

Important to know is, that your redirect is a redirect to a new URL and your not directly responding with a new view.

Answer (score 2):

Normal redirect like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);
}
```

Send data with redirection (flash attribute data will not be visible in URL):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=GET)
public String yourMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   ...
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("rd", "rdValue");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fa", faValue);
   return "redirect:/someOtherURL";
}
```

As i can see from the code that you are trying to send data also along with redirection so use 2nd approach.

Also see this [spring-redirectattributes-addattribute-vs-addflashattribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470111/spring-redirectattributes-addattribute-vs-addflashattribute)